# Batch script to check if number of files in folder is less X and then execute command

Tags: batch-file

So I have a folder that processes the containing files automatically.
I have another folder that has thousands of files to be processed and I created a script that moves 100 files to that processing folder every hour with Task Scheduler, but I want to do it only if that destination folder has less than 20 files in it.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

```
@echo off

set Source=Source folder
set Target=Destination folder

set MaxLimit=100

for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B "%Source%\*.*" ^| find /v /n ""') do (
    move /y "%Source%\%%~nxH" "%Target%"
    if %%G==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
)
```

Comment: `for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%target%\*" ^|find /c /v ""') do set "remaining=%%a"` and `if %remaining% gte 20 goto :eof` ?

Comment: (sorry, it's `GEQ`, not `GTE`)

Comment: Can't get it to work anyway.

Can you suggest the whole code to see if i'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple count on files in the destination folder to determine if processing should occur using a condition check.

```
Set "Target=Destination folder"

Set count=0
FOR %%a IN (%Target%\*.*) DO (
    Set /a count+=1
)

If %count% LSS 20 (
    GOTO process
) else (
    EXIT
)

:process

"Insert your Move command Here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the files in the target location and exit if there are enough

```
@echo off

set Source=Source folder
set Target=Destination folder
set MaxLimit=100

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%target%\*" ^|find /c /v ""') do set "remaining=%%a" 
if %remaining% geq 20 (
  echo enough files in target; nothing to do.
  goto :eof
)

for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%G in ('dir /A-D /B "%Source%\*.*" ^| find /v /n ""') do (
    move /y "%Source%\%%~nxH" "%Target%"
    if %%G==%MaxLimit% exit /b 0
)
```

Comment: By the way, the 100 files i move, how can i move the newer ones first?

Comment: Simple: add the `/o-d` switch to the `dir` command (see `dir /?`)

Comment: It goes like this:

dir /A-D /B /O-D

Right?

Comment: that's correct. (`/OD` to move the oldest first, `/O-D` for newest first)

Answer (score 0):

Or count the files in the destination folder and only process if there are less than your defined quantity:

```bat
@Set "SrcDir=Source folder"
@Set "DstDir=Destination folder"
@Set /A "MaxCnt=100,MinCnt=20"
@For /F %%A In ('""%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" "%DstDir%\*" ? /LSHQ 2>NUL"'
)Do @If %%A Lss %MinCnt% For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=[]" %%B In (
    '"Dir /B/A-D/O-D "%SrcDir%"|"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /V /N """'
)Do @Move /Y "%SrcDir%\%%~nxC" "%DstDir%">NUL&If %%B Equ %MaxCnt% Exit /B 0
```